# Black Amiga 500 Keys

Tags: amiga, keyboards, hardware-mods

I am creating a black Amiga 500 casing for my retro pi unit. I have already bought the casing, a 1200 keyboard and keyrah unit to convert the keyboard to USB.

I have some vinyl dye paint for the plastic, but I also have a quandary regarding the keys. If I dye them black, are there any professional-looking white character transfers/stickers for the a500 keyboard characters available?

Or is there another solution to get black keys? I could get an old cd32 keyboard which was black, but the last time I checked eBay they were going for £100 and I'm not paying that much!

Comment: Go the really classy way and have no visible writing on the keycaps ;)

Comment: Please tell me you're not modding vintage equipment that drastically?  If so, this reminds me of the Mac aquariums that are just awful.  Are you saying you're gutting an A500 just to put a Raspberry Pi in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may have found a possible solution.

http://www.4keyboard.com/commodore/586-commodore-commodore-a500-a1200-a1200hd-non-transparent-keyboard-stickers-882798355421.html

The company above sell black stickers for A1200 keyboard caps. Anyone had any experience with these?

Comment: I've not used these myself, but some people I know in my local Commodore/Amiga User's Group bought those for their own black A500 mod, and they didn't mention any problems with them.

So I'd say go right ahead and grab them!